# read strings from an image file in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to read only the strings from an image file. I was able to successfully read all the strings in the image file using java. I wrapped the inputstream into a filereaderstream which is again wrapped inside of a bufferereader. so now i can extract all the strings from the image file (like xmp tags and exif, tiff tags etc) ..

how do i accomplish the same thing using c.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using unix based OS, you can use the (unix, not C) command [strings](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?strings).

Comment: wow.. the command line tool is great. but unfortunately i'm looking for something which can be done programmatically in C because i've other manipulations to do.

Comment: Can't you just pipe the output of strings to your tool which then does the other things you need?

Comment: the problem with strings is that its giving out all the printable characters. now i only need the characters starting from say "<xmpmeta" and ending with "</xmpmeta>".
I'm right now reading the available options in the man page... let me see if there's anything in there

Comment: You can use grep/sed/awk. btw, UTF8 is just a scheme of encoding, which you use to interpret the data. You need to _know_ it before hand, unless the data has the meta-data about the encoding mixed in. So looking for strings encoded in UTF8 does not seem to make much sense.